# Joomla - syntax explanation

Tags: joomla

In a view of joomla registration module, there is the string:

"registration.register"

What about this sintax?

The call bypass the controller and call a particullary function?

Answer (score 0):

It calls the function named "register" in the controller named "registration".

You can find that function inside the file "registration.php" in

```
/components/com_users/controllers/registration.php
```